# Would adding channel_shift_range to Keras preprocessing (image augmentation) allow the model to be used in variable light situations?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, light, coreml

I am currently creating a machine learning model with the ultimate goal of deploying the model in an iOS app. The app would be used in the field, where light conditions are highly variable compared to the testing and training set.

Would adding a high `channel_shift_range` to my image data generator improve my model's ability to recognize the images even when the light conditions are highly variable?

I am currently using

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=360,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        channel_shift_range=100,
        data_format=ch_format,
        brightness_range=(0.75, 1.25),
        fill_mode='nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  data_format=ch_format)
```

for my data generators and using `flow_from_directory` to load my images into the model.

On a conceptual level, would this work and create the desired results?
Also, if I added a `channel_shift_range` to the `test_datagen` would it more accurately reflect my model's performance in variable light situations?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would want to apply all sorts of data augmentation, not only `channel_shift_range`.

Note that, on principle, you should not touch your test dataset. In your case, if you apply a kind of augmentation on the training set, you do not want to apply it also on the test set.

The idea of using the augmentation is to provide the model with many examples, so that it is robust when it goes 'to production'. If you augmented the true test dataset in the exact way you augment the training set, you would just 'mini-cheat'; as you know you gave a lot of examples with, say `channel_shift_range` with value K to your training set, giving the same exact value to the test set would be just be almost like copying training data to your test data; you do not want to do that.

Ensure that you use a numerous and relevant augmentations in your case (for instance, color shift when comparing apples and oranges is not a wise augmentation).

Comment: Agree on the "don't add augmentation" to your test set. I just wanted to add that you should make sure the test set contains images where the light conditions are very variable. Otherwise you won't be able to tell if your model actually works well for such images.